# How to register key-value pairs of types at compile time?

Tags: c++

Let's say I got a class Test and a class TestImpl. I do not want to make the Impl be an inner class of Test. How can I at compile time create some global key-value (Type-Impl) repository where the type of Impl can be pulled using the Type?

Something like:

```
Impl<Test>::Type
```

This should result in TestImpl.

Comment: This seems like the sort of thing that could be handled with an ordinary preprocessor macro.  Is there some reason that wouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a generic template without an implementation, then specialize it:

```
template <typename T> struct Impl;
template<> struct Impl<Test> { typedef TestImpl Type; };
```

and so on, for each of the types you need.

Answer (score 1):

One convenient way to organize interfaces and implementations is to use a tag that associates them:

```
template<typename TAG> class interface;
template<typename TAG> class impl;

template<typename> struct impl_of;

template<typename TAG>
struct impl_of<interface<TAG> > { using type = impl<TAG>; };
```

Then define the folowing:

```
namespace tag {
   struct Test;
   struct Foo;
   struct Bar;
   // etc.
}

using Test = interface<tag::Test>;
using Foo = interface<tag::Foo>;
using Bar = interface<tag::Bar>;
// etc.
```

Now your actual class definitions will not be `Test`, `TestImpl` etc., but rather specializations:

```
template<>
class interface<tag::Test> {
    // Test class definition
};

template<>
class impl<tag::Test> {
    // TestImpl class definition
};
```

The required mapping in this case is provided by `impl_of`, which is only defined once.

This may sound too much, but is powerful if you are going to define many classes (like `interface`, `impl`) and many traits (like `impl_of`) on them.